# Is it okay to totally rewrite someone's question?

Tags: discussion

Today I notice [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487581/star-team-integration-with-windows-explorer) on hold question. As I write this it says:

> I want to integrate star team source control software into windows
>   explorer like Tortoise. Is it possible?

I thought I might re-write it to make it clearer what the person is asking for. I came up with this:

> With TortoiseSVN it's possible to work with Subversion source control
>   from within Windows Explorer. Is there anything similar for working
>   with StarTeam source control from within Windows Explorer?

But I realized that I would be totally re-writing the question. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Your proposed rewrite is ***still off-topic***, because it asks for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally spoken, what I think is essential here is to keep in mind: "Is this a good question?"

I feel like if after your edit it was a good question, and before it wasn't, yes, it would be fine to do this. But you should take care of not changing the essence of the question itself by doing so.

**Concerning the question you mention I feel like your edit wouldn't make it a good question**, as I think it is not well researched anyway.

Comment: The question, after the edit, still meets the same criteria for closure.

Comment: @Servy that's what my 3rd paragraph of the answer was meant to express.